# Why does my docker-compose port config work?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm in the process of creating a docker-compose config which maintains:

1. a node.js server, and
2. a separate postgres server.

Tutorials emphasise that postgres port 5432 must be exposed or forwarded so that the node container can access it: facilitated in the below `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:alpine
        ports:
            - "5010:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: verysecretpass
            POSTGRES_DB: pg-dev

    server:
        container_name: dashboard-api
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/server
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
```

This produces the below `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
0d790cd4929e   server_server     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   dashboard-api
818296c1fc02   postgres:alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:5010->5432/tcp   pg
```

In the above state, node gets ECONN REFUSED when attempting to connect with this url: `postgres://postgres:verysecretpass@db:5010/pg-dev`

Yet, the same connection string **can** connect when using 5432 instead of 5010.

In fact, using 5432, connection succeeds even when pg container has no port configuration whatsoever. The below `docker ps` output reflects no-port-config state in which node container can happily connect:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
76da96c15c05   server_server     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   dashboard-api
51c221ac2c54   postgres:alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   5432/tcp                 db
```

Why does this work? What am I missing here?

Using:

- Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3
- docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

Comment: when you're connecting using docker name, you're connecting to docker itself, not with the port mapped outside by docker proxy(5010), if you want to connect to 5010, just use localhost or public ip of your host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise configured, the services in a docker-compose document are [automatically added to a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). There's no need to expose ports in this network.

If you want to expose ports on a container to the outside world, you will need to explicitly map these as you did. This however does not change anything for communication between services in the same network. If you have no reason to access the database from outside the network (e.g. inspect data using a DB tool on your own machine), you don't have to map / expose any ports of the db container.